# Multi criteria sorting, with quick sort algorithm in c

Tags: c, sorting, struct, quicksort

I got a problem to sort list of student by their age, if the student have the same age with other student, the data will be sorted alphabetically. sorting the age is not a problem but sort the name at same time is a challenge.

i got no issue with bubble sort. but i have no idea how to do it with quick sort.

```
struct stduent{
    char name[1001];
    int age;
};
void sort(student data[], int left, int right){
    
    if(left<right){
        
        int pivot = partition(data,left,right);
        
        sort(data, left, pivot-1);
        sort(data, pivot+1, right);
        
    }
    return;
}

int partition(student data[], int left, int right){
    
    int pivot = data[right].age.
    int i = left;
    student temp;
    for(int j=left;j<right;j++){
        if(data[j].age<=pivot){
            temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = temp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    temp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[right];
    data[right] = temp;
    
    return i;
}
```

This is my function to sort the age of the student.

but i dunno where to put the second condition if the student have the same age.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The first thing to do is get in the habit of separating (both in your mind, and the code)  the sorting algorithm from the comparison algorithm.  Whenever you write a sort routine, never write `if(a[i] > a[j])`; instead write `if(compare(a[i], a[j]) > 0)` or `if(compare(&a[i], &a[j]) > 0)`.  That way, to sort on some different criteria, all you have to do is change the `compare` function.  (in the standard library, [`qsort`[(https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) accepts a function pointer, precisely to enable this distinction.)

Comment: Start writing a function `bool IsSmaller(struct student *lh, struct student *rh)`.

Comment: In your new-student-compare function, you need a multi-level comparison.  The general form is `if(a->field1 < b->field1) return -1; else if(a->field1 > b->field1) return +1; else if(a->field2 < b->field2) return -1; else if(a->field2 > b->field2) return +1; else return 0;`  That is, if neither `<` nor `>` is true when comparing on `field1`, that means the two records are equal on `field1`, and it's time to fall through to `field2`.  You can cascade through as many fields as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up both cases in condition ,

```
  if(data[j].age<=pivot)
```

You can try this approach with your own string comparison logic.

```
    if(data[j].age<pivot){
        temp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[j];
        data[j] = temp;
        i++;
    }

    else if(data[j].age == pivot){
        int q = nameCompare(data[j].name, data[right].name);
        if(q < 0){
          temp = data[i];
          data[i] = data[j];
          data[j] = temp;
          i++;
        }
        else //you can compare last name or anyhting you want..
    }
```

here, I am use nameCompare method, which return negative number if first string
is come first in alphabetical order than second string, return zero if both string are same otherwise return positive number.

If you want nameCompare() method specific comment below, or you can also create your own logic.